# Trouble installing Ruby 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby

I'm installing ruby 2.0.0 but some packages not found. first i use this command

```
rvm get stable
```

then i issue command

```
rvm requirements
```

i have these errors below

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

i try to install by following below

https://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppabut

but no success and on installing ruby 2.0.0 like below

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

give me same error

Can anyone please help.

Comment: what does blender have to do with installing ruby? :/ Also, you haven't followed the instructions in that post, otherwise you wouldn't be getting some of those errors.

Comment: when i give command rvm requirements i see that errors

Comment: you would have the same error when trying to update your system, if you have invalid third-party PPAs in your software sources. Remove them.

Comment: Yes, I also want to get it install in my pc.but never got success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the Blender package. Your system might be hung up on dependencies it can't resolve.

It looks like you're using a bad mirror. I'm not sure how to get Ubuntu to drop that mirror and use a working one, but in other systems it requires deleting the mirror cache file and rebuilding it.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. At last this help me out to find solution                 https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/207163